# XTR M960 Crank to Stages power meter compatibility

Tags: mountain-bike, compatibility, power

I want to buy a Stages power meter but my MTB has an old XTR M960 crankset. I wonder if a Stages XTR M980, M985, M9000 or M9020 left arm meter can be installed replacing the left crankarm of my old M960?

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

Comment: I edited your question to make it clear you want to add a Stages left arm meter to the existing M960 crank. Please re-edit of that is not what you meant.

Comment: If the connection to the existing crank-axle is compatible, which is, the new crank clears the frame and the different look doesn't offend your eyes, there is no problem. Just think of getting the correct length.

Comment: TYVM Carel so i can install any of Stages XTR M980, M985, M9000 or M9020 left arm in my XTR M960 crankset. thats it?

Comment: If it fits, yes!